# What's the better way to read a char?

Tags: c

i write a little code to simply read a char from the keyboard but the program fails, why? How must i read a char?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 char op;

 do
 {
  printf("¿Sigues?");
  scanf("%c",&op);
 }while(op=='s' || op=='S');
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: "the program fails", could you explain how the program fails?

Comment: It simply writes 2 times "Sigues" always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `%c` conversion specifier doesn't cause `scanf()` to skip leading whitespace.  You need to handle the newline character that's still in the stream after reading your input.

The input stream is empty when `scanf()` is called the first time through the loop, so it waits for you to type something.  You type `s` and hit the Enter key, so the input stream contains the characters `s` and `\n` (newline).  `scanf()` removes the `s` from the input stream and assigns it to `op`.  When `scanf()` is called the second time, the input stream is *not* empty; it still has the `\n` character in it, so `scanf()` reads it and assigns it to `op`, which causes the loop condition to fail, so your loop exits.

There are several ways to get around this problem.  I'm going to recommend reading *strings* as opposed to individual characters using `fgets()`, as follows:

```
char op[3] = {0}; // input character + newline character + 0 terminator

do
{
  printf("¿Sigues?");
  if (fgets(op, sizeof op, stdin))
  {
    /**
     * Check for a newline character in the input.  If it's not there
     * then the user typed in too many characters.  In order to keep
     * the input stream from getting clogged up with bad input, read
     * until we find a newline character.
     */
    char tmp[3];
    char *newline = strchr(op, '\n');
    while (!newline && fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin))
    {
      newline = strchr(tmp, '\n');
    }
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Error while reading input\n");
    op[0] = 0;
  }
} while (tolower(op[0]) == 's');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
op = getc(stdin);
```

Comment: Thank you very much,
Can you explain me the difference between them?

Comment: the loop in the original post will produce the same result as the `scanf("%c")`. `getc(stdin)` will still only read one char, and there will still be a `\n` in stdin.

Answer (score 1):

scanf flushes only after reading a newline. it cant be done in platform independent way

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the line "Sigues" twice because there's a `\n` still in the input stream. If you type in a character and hit enter there are now two characters in your input stream. Your `scanf` formatter only specifies one char, so `scanf` reads in one char and then advances. However,  the next character in the stream is a `\n`, hence the exit from the loop on the second go.

NB. @eduffy's technique of `getc(stdin)` will do the exact same thing, there's still a `\n` in stdin. You need to advance past that `\n` somehow.

How about reading in your char, and then chomping the rest of the stream up to the `\n` char? I tried this and it works for me:

```
char op;

do
 {
  printf("¿Sigues?");
  scanf("%c",&op);
  while(getchar() != '\n') continue;
}while(op=='s'|| op=='S');
```